# How can I convert a single Javadoc comment to HTML?

Tags: html, javadoc

I've written a tool to extract single Javadoc docmments for fields or methods for special documentation purposes. If you like, I'm writing my own Javadoc viewer (like the one in Eclipse).

I looked for an hour at the Javadoc HTML doclet sources trying to figure out how to convert **only** the Javadoc stored in **a single** FieldDoc or MethodDoc to HTML. If you want to have a look yourself, the sources can be found here:

- http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/tools/doclets/formats/html/
- http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/tools/javadoc/